# Parse digits from integer

Tags: java, integer, render, rectangles

I need to make a function that will fill a `Rectangle` with a color.
The method looks like this

```
public void fillRect(Rectangle rect, int color)
{
    int red = color;
    int green = color;
    int blue = color;
    g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
    g.fillRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY(), rect.getW(), rect.getH());
}
```

I would like to use an integer as parameter, for example `200100150` 
which would result in the value `200` for red (only the three first digits).

Is it possible to do this width java?

Comment: Convert it to `String`, use `substring` to get the elements you're interested in, convert them back to `int` - A "better" solution is to either used a "int packed color" (which `Color` supports) or pass in the `Color` directly

Comment: I would suggest having a look at [`Color(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-) and [`Color#getRGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB--) for some "different" ideas ;)

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with '%' and '/' operations like this:

```
int blue = color % 1000;
color /= 1000;

int green = color % 1000;
color /= 1000;

int red = color;
```

Also you could add a simple validation at the beginning

```
if(color <= 99_999_999) { // I'm pretty sure that you need at least JDK7 to use '_' notation
    //do sth
}
```

Comment: very neat solution, no messing with digits or even worse: Stringly typed stuff ;-)

Comment: For validation, didn't you mean `999_999_999`? --- Better validation would be to check that the 3 values are 0-255, since colors 256-999 are not valid.

Comment: @Andreas nope I did not mean 999_999_999 because "The lowest" value of color can be 100_000_000 ;) however you are kind of right and my validation is only the basic one (whether color int has 9 digits) and additional check for value ranges would be necessary

Comment: @m.antkowicz I agree with Andreas on this one for a different reason -- what happens if red, green, and/or blue are zero? For example, the color black would be 000000000 and fail your validation. Better to check the parsed values.

Comment: @JonathanLam you're right this is important border case that you need to check - but still - to split this int to 3 parts and validate them you need to ensure that it has 9 digits. All od this just leads me to thought that sending this color as one long digit is bad by design, problematic and not easy to support :)

Comment: @m.antkowicz Color White would be `255_255_255`, so with `color <= 99_999_999` you wouldn't allow White, or any other color with Red being 100-255.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number length (i.e., it looks like all your integers will be of length 9), you can use modulus and (integer) division:

```
int red = color / 1000000;
int green = color % 1000000 / 1000;
int blue = color % 1000;
```

If not, you can turn the integer into a String, get the first three characters as a substring, and convert it back to an integer.

Comment: same idea as mine but I really like your notation style :)

Comment: @m.antkowicz Yup you just beat me to it! Nice to mention the validation

Comment: Using `double` math for `int` calculations seems counter-intuitive. It's not that difficult to write `1000000` instead of `1e6`. --- You could do the `1e6` and keep `int` math by casting *before* applying the operator, e.g. `int red = color / (int)1e6;`, but why, since `(int)1e6` is 8 characters, and `1000000` is only 7, so you're not saving anything, and I think it's less readable too.

Comment: @Andreas My bad! For some reason I didn't pick up on the fact that using exponential notation produces a `double` value. I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Converting to a string and get Substrings and convert them to integers again? Great idea.Here is my code

```
public void setColor(int color)
{
    String newColor = Integer.toString(color);
    g.setColor(new Color(Integer.parseInt(newColor.substring(0, 3)),
                         Integer.parseInt(newColor.substring(3, 6)),
                         Integer.parseInt(newColor.substring(6, 9))));
}
```

It will be much slower than passing the integer to the Color()? 
Im new in java and i want to make things my way.

Comment: Converting to string and back is overkill, since simple division and remainder math can do it. But more importantly, the code will crash and burn if you e.g. want color black, since `color = 0` becomes `newColor = "0"` and all the `substring(...)` calls will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, making this answer not useful.

Comment: I find a solution. I calculated the differense between string length and number 9 and i add a 0 in front of newColor using a for loop.